# Format CSV to avoid errors

Tags: javascript

I have a csv file with text line like this.

```
text,"text1","text2, text3",text4,text5
```

I need to split this line into separate variables to represent columns like this. Using JavaScript.

```
column1="text1";
column2="text2, text3";
column3="text4";
column4="text5";
```

Comment: So what is the question? What have you tried doing?

Comment: maybe the use of different delimiter like semicolon ";" would help you. Splitting by commas when some commas don't count is just a pain in the ass. With semicolon as delimeter you would just go `var cols = line.split(';')`

Comment: I need it like that. Its too much manual work to change delimiter to ;